# UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed. MVC API C#

Tags: c#, api, uribuilder

I am trying to create my web application and I want to connect to API. I have base address in my `Startup.cs` file:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient("API Client", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://icanhazdadjoke.com/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
});
```

But now I want to change it in program by adding a `/search` to the url address. I am using `UriBuilder` and it looks like this:

```cs
string responseBody = "";
var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("API Client");
var builder = new UriBuilder(client.GetAsync("") + "/search");
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
query.Add("term", searchedTerm);
query.Add("limit", jokesPerPage);

builder.Query = query.ToString();
string url = builder.ToString();
responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JokeModel>(responseBody);
```

I got an error:

> UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is server secure (https) or non secure (http)?  If secure, you are failing the SSL/TLS certification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetAsync` executes a GET request whereas you presumably want to use the client's `BaseAddress` as the initial Uri to construct:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder(client.BaseAddress);
builder.Path = "/search";
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
query.Add("term", searchedTerm);
query.Add("limit", jokesPerPage);

builder.Query = query.ToString();
string url = builder.ToString();
```